# Armitage won't start: parse error

Tags: postgresql, kali, metasploit, rpc

I installed Armitage along with Metasploit and Postgresql but Armitage is not connecting.

Starting Postgresql works fine

```
sudo service postgresql start
 * Starting PostgreSQL 9.3 database server                    [ OK ]
```

Metasploit is working because typing `msfconsole` in the terminal loads metasploit.

However, when I start Armitage, I get stuck on the java connection window with "Parse Error".
When the loading is over, the window simply disappears and nothing happens.

This is the error I'm getting

> Connecting to 127.0.0.1:55553
>
> org.msgpack.UnpackException: parse error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. go to http://www.fastandeasyhacking.com/download and get the tgz file
2. extract it (`tar -xf armitage150813.tgz`) and open up the armitage folder you just downloaded.
3. now head over to `/usr/share/armitage` and replace all the contents in that folder with the new contents you just downloaded.
4. reboot for good measure

That should fix it.